# How to georeference an areal photograph given known coordinates of the four corners and center of the image

Tags: development, georeferencing

First, let me say that I am new to this field.  I have an existing image/video viewing application.  My primary goal is to implement an efficient method to determine the latitude and longitude of any pixel in an image or video frame.  I know the latitude and longitude of the four corners and the center of the image/frame.  I also know the projection system that the coordinates are based in.

The images in question are not maps.  They are areal photographs.  I cannot make assumptions about the viewing angle or anything like that.

I'm not looking to use any existing application or tool.  I need to implement the necessary functionality in my own application.  I am open to using a third party library if that's the best way, but my application is proprietary.  So licensing is a concern.

I've been looking into this for a while now.  I've read up on world files and using them for rectification.  But I don't know how to create one for my image.  It seems like the tutorials that I have seen make assumptions for simplicity sake that I cannot make.

I'm basically looking for a description of the necessary math to perform the required analysis and/or a good library I could use that is compatible with proprietary software.  My existing application is written in c++ and c#.

I apologize if any of terminology is incorrect.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that your Images are ALREADY georeferenced given that you already know the coordinates of your corner pixels.

Comment: Unless you do not have access to ArcGIS, it is the right tool for the job. Having said that, there a plethora of open source GIS (like QGIS) which will also provide the required functionality.  Writing a C++/C# code to georeference would be a bit of too much unnecessary hard work and re-inventing the wheel, when the objective is to have the image georeferenced. Use the following link to georeference in ArcMap: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t000000mq000000

Comment: use gdal_translate with argument a_ullr for "assign upper left, lower right.